# Размер элемента WPF на неактивной вкладке TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется `TabControl` с двумя вкладками, и на каждой, допустим, `Grid`. `TabControl` растянут по главному окну. При запуске программы активна первая вкладка. До тех пор, пока вторую вкладку не активируешь, `ActualWidth` и `ActualHeight` грида на второй вкладке остаются нулевыми.

Какие методы нужно вызвать и у кого, чтобы узнать актуальный размер элемента(ов) на скрытой вкладке?

Comment: Концепция прорисовки элементов в WPF такая, что они сами себя прорисовывают в момент передачи им размеров извне, которые они могут занять. Скорее всего `TabPanel` вызывает методы `Measure` и `Arrange` только в момент перехода передавая размеры, поэтому элемент понятия не имеет о своих размерах до момента перехода на вкладке. Можно конечно передать принудительно размеры от самого `TabControl` внутрь `Measure` и `Arrange`, но я понятия не имею как в этом случае поведет себя WPF и как внутри реализована логика прорисовки элемента себя и какие точно размеры передаются.

Comment: Ну то есть можно вручную вызвать `Measure` у элемента, и опросить `DesiredSize`. Но это очень низкоуровневый подход. Для чего вам это нужно?